# How do I print from a Python UDF in Pig?

Tags: python, apache-pig

I have a user-defined function written in Python that I call from a Pig script.  For debugging purposes, I'd like to print out some of my variables, but my print statements don't seem to have any effect.  How do I print from a Python UDF in Pig?

Comment: use apache commons log facility instead of stdout? `import org.apache.commons.logging.Log; import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory; # see also pigLogger`

Answer (score 0):

in general if you just print as in example below (which works for me) it will go to the log of the task which will perform the UDF. the complicated part here is to find the the relevant map/reduce task which produced it through the job tracker (in pig 11 it is more simple as pig write each phase to stdout)

```
@outputSchema("schema:chararray")
def convertBagToStr(acctBag):
    #print len(acctBag)
    #print acctBag
    return "_".join([str(i[0]) for i in sorted(acctBag)])
```